# Run and refresh a jupyter notebook every 5 m

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a working Python script which runs in a Jupyter Notebook by querying a database and rendering the results as an HTML cell in the notebook. I would like to automate the execution of this so that it can refresh the results every 15 minutes.

I can do this manually by selecting Kernel -> Restart and Run All, but I am looking for a way to just let this run by itself so that I can use it as a dashboard view.

Answer (score 2):

What about to run:

```
jupyter nbconvert --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --to notebook --execute your_notebook.ipynb
```

Then, you can add the execution to a cron job or some kind of scheduler.

Comment: Thanks - I tried running this and it appears to run the jupyter notebook and save it to the local folder, but doesn't print output to the screen.